# Can fold be used to create infinite lists?

Tags: haskell

I have written the following code which creates an infinite list of Fibonacci numbers:

```
fibs = 1:1:fib 1 1
  where fib a b = a+b:fib b (a+b)
```

Can the above code be written using `foldl` or `foldr` to avoid recursion?

Comment: Although this is interesting, there is actually a better way to do this which is to use the [closed form solution for finding the Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding)

Comment: @AndrewWalker, with floating point arithmetic, that's not an exact solution.

Comment: Note that in a non-strict functional language like Haskell, there's no cause to avoid recursion for efficiency reasons, but it's fine to avoid it for stylistic reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to create infinite lists with `foldl`. You could perhaps solve this problem by using `foldr`, but then you would have to create another list to fold over. What would that list be? There is nothing with the fibonacci numbers that suggest they are generated from some other list.

What you want instead is to use `unfoldr`. It can be used to create lists instead of consuming them, as is the case for `foldl` and `foldr`. Here's how you would use `unfoldr` to generate the infinite list of fibonacci numbers.

```
fib = unfoldr (\(a,b) -> Just (a,(b,a+b))) (1,1)
```

You can find `unfoldr` in the module `Data.List` in the base package.

Answer (score 15):

The `foldl` and `foldr` functions are list-*consumers*. As [svenningsson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298382/828361) rightly points out, `unfoldr` is a list-*producer* which is suitable for capturing the *co*-recursive structure of `fibs`.

However, given that `foldl` and `foldr` are polymorphic in their return types, i.e. what they're producing by consuming a list, it is reasonable to ask whether they might be used to consume one list and produce another. Might any of these produced lists be infinite?

Looking at the definition of `foldl`

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl f a []        = a
foldl f a (b : bs)  = foldl f (f a b) bs
```

we see that for `foldl` to produce anything at all, the list it consumes must be finite. Thus if `foldl f a` produces infinite output, it is because `a` is infinite or because `f` sometimes performs infinite list generation.

It's a different story with `foldr`

```
foldr :: (b -> a -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldr f a []        = a
foldr f a (b : bs)  = f b (foldr f a bs)
```

which admits the lazy possibility that `f` might generate some output for each `b` consumed from the input. Operations like

```
map g = foldr (\ b gbs -> g b : gbs) []   -- golfers prefer ((:) . g)
stutter = foldr (\ x xxs -> x : x : xxs) []
```

producing a little bit of output for each input, deliver infinite output from infinite input.

A cheeky person can thus express any infinitary recursion as a non-recursive `foldr` on an infinite list. E.g.,

```
foldr (\ _ fibs -> 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)) undefined [1..]
```

(Edit: or, for that matter

```
foldr (\_ fib a b -> a : fib b (a + b)) undefined [1..] 1 1
```

which is closer to the definition in the question.)

although this observation, whilst true, is hardly indicative of a healthy programming style.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is very interesting. But using fib to call fib again uses **recursion** which we try to avoid using fold.

Comment: The `fib` in my term is bound with a lambda, not defined by recursion. On the other hand, it's true that I'm using `foldr` to construct a general purpose fixpoint operator.

Comment: In your foldl definition you omitted application of **f** so `foldl f a (b : bs)  = foldl (f a b) bs` had to be `foldl f a (b : bs)  = foldl f (f a b) bs`

Answer (score 3):

One way to avoid explicit recursion is to use [`fix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v%3afix) to express the recursion as a fixed point.

```
import Data.Function (fix)

fibs = fix $ \l -> [1,1] ++ zipWith (+) l (tail l)
```

or in point-free style

```
import Data.Function (fix)
import Control.Monad.Instances

fibs = fix $ ([1,1] ++) . (zipWith (+) =<< tail)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zipWith` to write your definition

```
fibonacci = 1:1:zipWith (+) fibonacci (tail fibonacci)
```

edit:
Ok, I dont think you can use foldl or foldr to create infinite list. Not in any simple imaginable sense. 
If you look at the simple definition of foldl

```
foldl f z []     = z
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs
```

foldl never returns until it has exhausted the whole list. 
So a simple example like

```
g = foldl f [] [1..]
 where 
  f xs a = xs ++ [a]

> take 10 g
```

will not work even and it will loop on forever.