# Is it possible to make GHC optimize (deforest) generic functions such as catamorphisms?

Tags: optimization, haskell, ghc, fusion, catamorphism

I really like the idea of working with catamorphisms/anamorphisms in a generic way, but it seems to me it has a significant performance drawback:

Suppose we want to work with a tree structure in the categorical way - to describe different folding using a generic [catamorphism function](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Catamorphisms):

```
newtype Fix f = Fix { unfix :: f (Fix f) }

data TreeT r = Leaf | Tree r r
instance Functor TreeT where
    fmap f Leaf         = Leaf
    fmap f (Tree l r)   = Tree (f l) (f r)

type Tree = Fix TreeT

catam :: (Functor f) => (f a -> a) -> (Fix f -> a)
catam f = f . fmap (catam f) . unfix
```

Now we can write functions like:

```
depth1 :: Tree -> Int
depth1 = catam g
  where
    g Leaf       = 0
    g (Tree l r) = max l r
```

Unfortunately, this approach has a significant drawback: During the computation, new instances of `TreeT Int` are created at every level in `fmap` just to be immediately consumed by `g`. Compared to the classical definition

```
depth2 :: Tree -> Int
depth2 (Fix Leaf) = 0
depth2 (Fix (Tree l r)) = max (depth1 l) (depth1 r)
```

our `depth1` will be always slower making unnecessary strain on the GC. One solution would be to use [hylomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylomorphism_%28computer_science%29) and combine creation and folding trees together. But often we don't want to do that, we may want a tree to be created on one place and then passed somewhere else to be folded later. Or, to be folder several times with different catamorphisms.

Is there a way to make GHC optimize `depth1`? Something like inlining `catam g` and then [fusing/deforesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforestation_%28computer_science%29) `g . fmap ...` inside?

Comment: I'm late to this party, but shouldn't there be a `+1` somewhere in the `Tree` case of `g` (or `depth2`) for the function to calculate the depth of the tree? Otherwise, I can't see how `depth1` or `depth2` can return anything but zero.

Comment: Also, I think `depth1` should actually be `depth2` in `depth2`'s definition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe I found an answer. I remembered reading [Why does GHC make fix so confounding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999385/why-does-ghc-make-fix-so-confounding) and that suggested me a solution.

The problem with the former definition of `catam` is that it is recursive, and so any attempt to [INLINE](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#inline-pragma) it is ignored. Compiling the original version with  `-ddump-simpl -ddump-to-file` and reading the [core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core):

```
Main.depth1 = Main.catam_$scatam @ GHC.Types.Int Main.depth3

Main.depth3 =
  \ (ds_dyI :: Main.TreeT GHC.Types.Int) ->
    case ds_dyI of _ {
      Main.Leaf -> Main.depth4;
      Main.Tree l_aah r_aai -> GHC.Classes.$fOrdInt_$cmax l_aah r_aai
    }

Main.depth4 = GHC.Types.I# 0

Rec {
Main.catam_$scatam =
  \ (@ a_ajB)
    (eta_B1 :: Main.TreeT a_ajB -> a_ajB)
    (eta1_X2 :: Main.Fix Main.TreeT) ->
    eta_B1
      (case eta1_X2
            `cast` (Main.NTCo:Fix <Main.TreeT>
                    :: Main.Fix Main.TreeT ~# Main.TreeT (Main.Fix Main.TreeT))
       of _ {
         Main.Leaf -> Main.Leaf @ a_ajB;
         Main.Tree l_aan r_aao ->
           Main.Tree
             @ a_ajB
             (Main.catam_$scatam @ a_ajB eta_B1 l_aan)
             (Main.catam_$scatam @ a_ajB eta_B1 r_aao)
       })
end Rec }
```

is clearly worse (constructor creation/elimination in `catam_$scatam`, more function calls) compared to

```
Main.depth2 =
  \ (w_s1Rz :: Main.Tree) ->
    case Main.$wdepth2 w_s1Rz of ww_s1RC { __DEFAULT ->
    GHC.Types.I# ww_s1RC
    }

Rec {
Main.$wdepth2 [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: Main.Tree -> GHC.Prim.Int#
[GblId, Arity=1, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType S]
Main.$wdepth2 =
  \ (w_s1Rz :: Main.Tree) ->
    case w_s1Rz
         `cast` (Main.NTCo:Fix <Main.TreeT>
                 :: Main.Fix Main.TreeT ~# Main.TreeT (Main.Fix Main.TreeT))
    of _ {
      Main.Leaf -> 0;
      Main.Tree l_aaj r_aak ->
        case Main.$wdepth2 l_aaj of ww_s1RC { __DEFAULT ->
        case Main.$wdepth2 r_aak of ww1_X1Sh { __DEFAULT ->
        case GHC.Prim.<=# ww_s1RC ww1_X1Sh of _ {
          GHC.Types.False -> ww_s1RC;
          GHC.Types.True -> ww1_X1Sh
        }
        }
        }
    }
end Rec }
```

But if we define `catam` as

```
{-# INLINE catam #-}
catam :: (Functor f) => (f a -> a) -> (Fix f -> a)
catam f = let u = f . fmap u . unfix
          in u
```

then it is no longer recursive, only `u` inside is. This way GHC inlines `catam` in the definition of `depth1` and fuses `fmap` with `depth1`'s `g` - just what we want:

```
Main.depth1 =
  \ (w_s1RJ :: Main.Tree) ->
    case Main.$wdepth1 w_s1RJ of ww_s1RM { __DEFAULT ->
    GHC.Types.I# ww_s1RM
    }

Rec {
Main.$wdepth1 [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: Main.Tree -> GHC.Prim.Int#
[GblId, Arity=1, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType S]
Main.$wdepth1 =
  \ (w_s1RJ :: Main.Tree) ->
    case w_s1RJ
         `cast` (Main.NTCo:Fix <Main.TreeT>
                 :: Main.Fix Main.TreeT ~# Main.TreeT (Main.Fix Main.TreeT))
    of _ {
      Main.Leaf -> 0;
      Main.Tree l_aar r_aas ->
        case Main.$wdepth1 l_aar of ww_s1RM { __DEFAULT ->
        case Main.$wdepth1 r_aas of ww1_X1So { __DEFAULT ->
        case GHC.Prim.<=# ww_s1RM ww1_X1So of _ {
          GHC.Types.False -> ww_s1RM;
          GHC.Types.True -> ww1_X1So
        }
        }
        }
    }
end Rec }
```

which is now just the same as the dump of `depth2`.

Comment: It seems that any recursive function can be transformed into a non-recursive function by moving its body to a local binding as in `catam` above. This looks like a simple step which facilitates optimization. I wonder why GHC does not do it automatically.