# Can one express catamorphism through Data.Function.fix?

Tags: haskell, recursion, optimization, fixpoint-combinators, catamorphism

I have this lovely `fixana` function here that performs about 5 times faster than her sister `ana`. *(i have a `criterion` report to back me on this)*

```
ana alg = Fix . fmap (ana alg) . alg

fixana alg = fix $ \f -> Fix . fmap f . alg
```

Can I express their cousin `cata` in the same fashion?

```
cata f = f . fmap (cata f) . unFix
```

It seems to me that I cannot, but I have been humbled by my S.O. fellows quite a few times in the past.

Comment: I don't understand. What happens if you try the analogous `fixcata f = fix $ \g -> f . fmap g . unFix` ?

Comment: @chi Oh. Defeated again. I'm poor with fixpoints. I should probably delete this question to avoid embarrassment.

Comment: SO is not a game when one gets "defeated" :) There's nothing wrong in asking a question without knowing the answer beforehand -- indeed that's the whole point of asking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this has nothing to do with catamorphisms.

Whenever a function is defined as

```
f = (... f ...)   -- some expression involving f
```

one can rewrite it using `fix` as

```
f = fix $ \g -> (... g ...)
```

In the posted code we have a slight variant

```
f x = (... (f x) ...)
```

We can regard the above as `f` being defined recursively. However, it's simpler if we regard `f x` (rather than `f`) being defined recursively.

```
f x = fix $ \g -> (... g ...)
```

This should be more efficient than the plain translation

```
f = fix $ \g x -> (... (g x) ...)
```

since we don't need to call `g` over and over again with the same argument `x`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you also take a look at the updated post?

Comment: @Kindaro you should make that update (which I rolled back for now) a separate question, since it doesn't directly relate to the original question's title.

Comment: @Kindaro Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999385/why-does-ghc-make-fix-so-confounding) first. I think it's exactly the same issue which improves performance.